# having a growing dict. deleting entries or not for better performance?

Tags: python, performance

I have a constantly growing dict within my python program. (The program constantly adds keys.)

I do not need the stored keys anymore after a certain amount of time, I know when this happens. No additional check is needed for deletion of the stored keys.

I was wondering if deleting the keys is more impactful on the performance then leaving the keys in the dict?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache ?

Comment: That depends on so many factors that it's impossible to say. You'll just have to try it and see if it's worth doing.